# empty variable getting saved before value is returned from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to save a data using the below query

```
var content = framejson($(e.target));
        //alert(wpId);
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function(){
        saveWebPartProperties(wpId, { Description: content }).done(function () {
                dfd.resolve();
                $(e.target).closest("table").find(".successmessage").show();
            }).fail(self.error);
        },500);
```

The code for framejson is below

```
function framejson(elem){
var listname={};
listname["Name"] = $(elem).closest("table").find(".Name").val();
listname["Length"] = $(elem).closest("table").find(".Length").val();
return JSON.stringify(listname);
};
```

Now in the code where I am trying to save the json content, empty value gets saved when I remove the alert or remove the `setTimeout`

It works fine only if I have the alert or `setTimeout` or if I debug via console

I also tried to use `deferred` and `when` but it didn't work. Only setTimeout is making it work and I am trying to understand why

```
var content = $.Deferred();
        content.resolve(framejson($(e.target)));
        $.when(content).done(function(){
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            saveWebPartProperties(wpId, { Description: content }).done(function () {
                dfd.resolve();
                $(e.target).closest("table").find(".successmessage").show();
            }).fail(self.error);
        });
```

What is the mistake that is causing this issue?

Comment: what is your `saveWebPartProperties`code ?

Comment: its a snippet that i got from here https://sharepointsamurai.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/how-to-use-the-csom-to-update-sharepoint-web-part-properties/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this snippet, this works fine.
So I guess your problem isn't in this showed code.

```js
$(".test").on('click', function(e){
  var content = framejson(e.target);
  console.log(content)
});

function framejson(elem){
   var listname={};
   listname["Name"] = $(elem).closest("table").find(".Name").val();
   listname["Length"] = $(elem).closest("table").find(".Length").val();
   return JSON.stringify(listname);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="Name" value="bla" /></td>
    <td><input class="Length" value="ert" /></td>
    <td><button class="test">test</button></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked,

```
var wpId=$(e.target).parents().closest(".ms-rtestate-field").parent().attr("webpartid");
        var content = $.Deferred();
        content.resolve(framejson($(e.target)));
        $.when(content).done(function(value){
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            saveWebPartProperties(wpId, { Description: value }).done(function () {
                dfd.resolve();
                $(e.target).closest("table").find(".successmessage").show();
            }).fail(self.error);
        });
```

I think the reason is, before the content is returned value from the framejson function, the save part is getting called

I have used `deferred` and `when` to resolve this problem. Once the content gets value returned from the function, the rest of the code is getting called for saving it